# Showing that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^n$ can't be a homeomorphism for $n>2$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Without using the Invariance of Domain result, I want to show that such an f cannot exist. Here is what I did:

Assume that there is an $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^n \ , n>2$ that is homeomorphic.

Consider $U = \left\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^2: r\leq \|x\| \leq R  \text{ for some } 0<r<R \right\rbrace$ 
and
$ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus{U} \to \mathbb{R}^n \setminus f(U)$.

The inverse of f is continuous, but $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus f(U)$ is simply connected and the pre-image is not!

---

What is wrong with this argument? I understand that $f(U)$ doesn't necessarily have to be an annulus, but slap on some continuous $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and it will be one.

Also, I was suggested that creating a quotient space can reduce the case back to $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I thought about two equivalence relation:

$x \sim y \iff \|x\|= \|y\|$  w.r.t. Euclidean norm.

$(x_{1},x_{2}) = x$; 
$x \sim y \iff x_{1}= y_{1}$

Would either of these be alright? I am aware the first one creates a half line. I have had no practice with quotient space so I'd rather not dabble in it, to be honest.

Thanks.

Comment: Looking for embeddings of annuli in $\mathbb R^n$ is asking for trouble. Try looking at $f: \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} \to \mathbb R^n$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your argument goes like this: the annulus $U$ is homotopic to a circle, and since $f$ is a homeomorphism its image $f(U)$ is also homotopic to a circle. This means that unless $f$ is the constant map, $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus f(U)$ amounts to $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus a wedge of circles, which is not simply connected. For example, think of a loop that links nontrivially with one of these circles; this loop cannot contract to a point.

Like William suggests, taking away a single point is the better strategy here.

Comment: That was silly of me. What about just path connected, though? I will take yours and William's suggestion and make U a point.

Comment: No, you should keep using simply connected. Think about it: is $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$ simply connected? What about $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$?

Comment: $ \mathbb {R}^2-$ {0}  is not simply connected (Not able to contract a curve continuously without the transforming curve crossing (0,0)). $$ \mathbb {R}^n- f(0) $$ is (shift it some $\delta$ >0 away on the normal vector direction if it lies on the same plane as (0,0). I've got it now, thanks. I have no idea why I struggled.